# Html upper and lower indecies

Tags: html, css, markup

any ways to put into html using css upper or lower indecies like: ¹ or ₁ (I also need latin letters).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HTML TAGS:** try sup and sub tags,...

[Demo](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_sup)

Other Option Using css:

```css
.sup,
.sub {
  height: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  _vertical-align: bottom;
  position: relative;
}

.sup {
  bottom: 1ex;
}

.sub {
  top: .5ex;
}
```

```html
text <span class=sup>upper</span><span class=sub>lower</span>
```

Answer (score 14):

Use the `<sup>` and `<sub>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want with latin letters or if you know what latin letters are, but the unicodes you can find here http://unicodelookup.com/#latin

In case you mean roman numbers, there is no automatic translation in HTML, except for an ol

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.sub, .sup { position: relative; font-size: 80%; }
</style>
...    
<span class=sub>a</span> (subscript)
<span class=sup>a</span> (superscript)
```

Tune the values as desired. In particular, you may wish to use different classes for different situations, especially depending on the letter that a superscript is attached to. For example, after an uppercase letter like “A,” a superscript should be placed considerably higher.

Why classes and CSS?

Although HTML appears to have just the right markup for this, `sup` and `sub`, they have several drawbacks. Their rendering is inconsistent across browsers and often typographically poor: both the vertical placement and the size can inadequate. It might seem easy to fix this in CSS, but it isn’t, due to an odd IE bug with sizing them: it interprets percentages incorrectly. Moreover, `sup` and `sub` often create uneven line spacing.

If you intend to use `sup` and `sub`, run some tests before starting to use them extensively. Test on a few browsers and with superscripts and subscripts inside text paragraphs (so that you see the line spacing issue).