# How to produce this special character for html displaying?

Tags: html

If i try to reproduce this character it shows as a plain simple 2

[image]

Someone got an idea how I can reproduce it? it is a 2 that is below the normal textflow and is a bit smaller.

Comment: `H<sub>2</sub>O` works if you need plain HTML.

Comment: @13ruce1337 add that as an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Html upper and lower indecies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793784/html-upper-and-lower-indecies)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to use subscript in HTML, the element `<sub></sub>` works fine. There is also `<sup></sup>` for superscript.

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/J9gdD/): `H<sub>2</sub>0`

[reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sub)

Comment: just saying: `<sub>` elements vertical-align: sub, which actually produces this effect, seems to be different in browser. Since I saw the the CSS reset is setting it to baseline. Just saying

Answer (score 1):

HTML..

```
<font color="CYAN"><sub><u>2</u></sub></font>
```

But oh noes! The u tag is deprecated in HTML5. Well, alrighty then.

Time for inline CSS shenanigans.. With a benefit, underline will still work if CSS is disabled thus cater to assistive modes, which is like, a big deal at W3C.

```
<u style="color:cyan;text-decoration:none;border-bottom: 1px solid cyan;"><sub>2</sub></u>
```

Looks like it did the job.

Comment: I assumed the underline was a link. In html the underline is preserved for links. [And in the spirit of html](http://jsfiddle.net/J9gdD/2/)

Comment: W3C site: "The <u> element is redefined in HTML5, to represent text that should be stylistically different from normal text, such as misspelled words or proper nouns in Chinese."